# How did the society where the story of Shin Sekai Yori takes place come to be?

Tags: from-the-new-world

How did the society where the story of Shin Sekai Yori takes place come to be? i.e. How did Saki's Society came to existence from the societies of the Dark age?

I am curious about how Saki's society came to be because, in her society, there is knowledge about science (implied from their knowledge about genes). However, part of it is also mixed with aspects of less modern societies, which makes me want to know how these different aspects came about, from previous societies during the Dark age.

Furthermore, there are these "creatures" called false Minoshiro which seem to be some kind of very advanced bio-technology, which suggest very advanced technology (but their society doesn't really live that way). With these different aspects of ancient Japanese societies and much newer societies, how did Saki's society came to existence? Why does it have this mix of modern technology and more ancient aspects? What happened to the previous Dynasties during the dark age? Did they combine/converge to form the modern society which Saki lives at? From which dynasty from the Dark age did they come from and what do we know that explains their present society?

As a refresher, here are some of the dynasties from the dark age:

- 1st, Slave Dynasties, Where PK users controlled those without PK capabilities.
- 2nd, non-PK users who escaped the Dynasties and lived as hunter-gatherers.
- 3rd, Bandits who used PK to attack other settlements.
- 4th, a group of those who managed to preserve some remnants of the technological age.

Comment: It's a common [trope](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/Days_of_Future_Past) used in fiction. As for how it came to be? I guess given enough time anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually explained a bit at one point, though I can't remember the episode exactly.

Essentially, humanity got really violent and started destroying each other, probably via nuclear warfare or maybe previous people with supernatural powers. Shin Sekai Yori takes place on one of the remaining human colonies, where the elders are the only ones that know of the leftover science, knowledge from the previous era.

This explains why they're super paranoid about these kids with powers, because they're afraid that everyone will get destroyed again.